# TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model user that has many realtionships

```
{
   username: DS.attr('string'),
   challenges: DS.hasMany('challenge', {async: true, inverse: 'author'}), 

  trials: DS.hasMany('trial',{async: true, inverse: 'user'}),
  arenasTried: DS.hasMany('arenaTrial',{async: true, inverse: 'user'}),

  groups: DS.belongsTo('group',{async: true, inverse: 'founder'}),
  group: DS.hasMany('group',{async: true, inverse: 'members'})
}
```

my '/api/users' route returns

```
 {
   users: [{
    _id: "53fcd802647d05af65227306"
    arenasTried: [53fcde1006c57af668f39e49]
    challenges: []
    email: "st@email.com"
    exp: 1
    group: null
    groups: []
    role: "student"
    rp: 0
    trials: [53fcde1006c57af668f39e4a, 53fcde1006c57af668f39e4b]
    username: "stud"
 }, ...]
```

}

I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the stack trace, I started by throwing a breakpoint where undefined value was popping up.
I noticed that it didn't happen the first time and had to click resume a few times, for lack of a stop before exception option I had to count the number of times before the error occurred and stop one value before.

every time I'd look around which allowed me to figure out that factory.typeKey usually has tt do with a relationship so I started looking up the stack trace until I found out that when key = 'groups'  on line 11750: `data[key] = store.recordForId(id.type, id.id);`  id.type was undefined

I thought first maybe it has something to do with the groups array being empty, but challenges was also an empty array, so to experiment I changed the JSON response to return only the challenges, and no error was thrown.

since I learned from another question that the typeKey error has to do with ember-data getting something it didn't expect I knew it really must have something to do with the way I'm defining the group relationship, and sure enough I noticed that I had inverted the definition of group and groups, where it was excepting groups to be a belongsTo rather then a hasMany relationship, I switched it and it worked.